# Why does the computed property return undefined?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I've got a component rendered as

```
{{foo-bar a=true}}
```

​In the component object, I have

```
b: Ember.computed.not('a')
```

Why does ​`b`​ return ​`undefined`​

Comment: I can't see a reason why it would. Can you reproduce this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code you supplied returns `false` correctly for property `b`. You probably access `b` property wrong and that's the reason for returning `undefined`. Even if you access `b` in component `init` hook it will correctly return false. Make sure you didn't make any errors and you use `{{b}}` in component template or `this.get('b')` in component code.

[See demo that shows your code is working.](http://ember-twiddle.com/ee6a2de0c288cd1c407e)